# What does it mean when you differentiate and get a constant value?

Tags: calculus

The diagram shows the values of $y=x^3$ and $y=4x$.

There is a vertical line $AB$. Find the maximum length of $AB$.

I differentiated $y=4x$ as I knew it would give me a constant value. I obviously got $4$.

But what does this mean? Does that mean my $x$ value is $4$ as $y$ does not change?

Comment: 1. Can you explain the term "differentiation" in your own words first? 2. What is AB?

Comment: There is no diagram attached to the OP. Also be aware that if you are taking the derivative of a vertical line (AB), the slope (derivative) is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

No, it means $y$ changes as much as $4$ times of changes in $x$.

Derivative captures how much the changes of $y$ in accordance with changes in $x$, locally. A constant derivative means the change-relationship are constant in all places of $x$.

If you have a graph of $y=4x$, you'll see this pretty clearly.

Also even if you do not take the derivative, $y=4x$, any change in $
\delta x$ will result in as much as of $4\delta x$ changes in for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

If the derivative is constant then the function in question has constant slope. These are your lines $y=mx+b$, and the slope is the same for any $x$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Differentiation gives the slope of a function. Hence, if $y(x) = 4x$, then the slope of $y$ is $4$ (i.e. differentiating $y$ gives $4$).